# Google Apps Script: Cannot get data from object loaded from ScriptDB

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

After receiving the object from scriptDB I cannot get access to some of its fields. This field with numeric keys. If you uncomment the line

```
//  var item2 = obj2['test']['2']['f']
```

it will cause a runtime error.

Full code is:

```
function test() {
  var obj1 = 
      {
        type: 'object',
        name: 'test',
        test: 
        {
          F: 'foo',
          B: {f: 'foooo', b: 'baaar', },
          1: 'foo',
          2: {f: 'foooo', b: 'baaar', },
        },
      };

  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
  var id = db.save(obj1).getId();
  var obj2 = db.load(id);

  db.removeById(id);

  var item1 = obj1['test']['2']['f']; // item1 = "foooo"
//  var item2 = obj2['test']['2']['f']; // Runtime error!

  var item3 = obj2['test']; // item3 = ({'2':{f:"foooo", b:"baaar"}, F:"foo", '1':"foo", B:{f:"foooo", b:"baaar"}})
  var item4 = obj2['test']['2']; // item4 = undefined!!! Why?!!!  
  var item5 = obj1['test']['2']; // item5 = ({f:"foooo", b:"baaar"})
  var item6 = obj2['test']['B']; // item6 = ({f:"foooo", b:"baaar"})
  var item7 = obj2['test']['B']['f']; // item7 = "foooo"

  return
}
```

As you can see, it is impossible to get object:

```
var item4 = obj2['test']['2']; // item4 = undefined
```

At the same time:

```
var item5 = obj1['test']['2'];
```

returns correct object from original obj1, and

```
var item6 = obj2['test']['B'];
```

returns a similar object from obj2. What's the problem?

P.S. The only difference between obj1 and obj2 (before and after saving them scriptDB) - presence of quotes in the numeric keys in obj2.

Comment: If your object key is a number, it should be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: Ofcourse I tried it...

Comment: very VERY bad idea to use numeric field names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should star [issue 3390](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3390) (posted by Zig Mandel).

Now talking solutions to your problem. The best thing is to void using numeric keys, but if you can't do that, then an easy workaround is to stringify and re-parse the object returned by the `ScriptDb`.

```
var obj2 = JSON.parse(db.load(id).toJson());
```

The down-side of doing this that you can't not modify `obj2` and then save your updates back to `ScriptDb`. If you don't use the object id anywhere else you can always remove the original object and save the "changes" as a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bad idea to use numeric properties thou it should work. It doesnt work because of this: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3390

Comment: Note this issue isn't limited to ScriptDb. I'm using Google Apps Script as a sort of an ORM for a spreadsheet that I have to update from external sources through the Execution API, and passing an argument that looks like `{"id":{"key":"value"}}`, where `id` is the row number, and the same thing is happening. The currently accepted answer worked.